# Python miminum length/max value in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, min

Had to re-write the question due to changed requirements.

I have a dictionary such as the following:

```
d = {'a': [4, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 3], 'd': [4, 3], 'e': [4], 'f': [4], 'g': [4]}
```

I want to get the keys that are associated with the smallest length in the dictionary d, as well as those that have the maximum value.

In this case, the keys with the smallest length (smallest length of lists in this dictionary) should return

```
'e, 'f', 'g'
```

And those with the greatest value(the sum  of the integers in each list) should return

```
'b' 'c'
```

I have tried

```
min_value = min(dict.itervalues())
min_keys = [k for k in d if dict[k] == min_value]
```

But that does not give me the result I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like something a filtering operation could do for you.

Comment: You *just* asked this question but changed one small detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python miminum value in dictionary of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729670/python-miminum-value-in-dictionary-of-lists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def get_smallest_length(x):
    return [k for k in x.keys() if len(x.get(k))==min([len(n) for n in x.values()])]

def get_largest_sum(x):
    return [k for k in x.keys() if sum(x.get(k))==max([sum(n) for n in x.values()])]

x = {'a': [4, 2], 'c': [4, 3], 'b': [3, 4], 'e': [4], 'd': [4, 3], 'g': [4], 'f': [4]}

print get_smallest_length(x)
print get_largest_sum(x)
```

Returns:

```
['e', 'g', 'f']
['c', 'b', 'd']
```